# How to include jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on Chrome extension and I have script file that is not background script and not content script, its script that I execute by chrome.tabs.executeScript. How do I use jQUery inside this script? I can't use `<script src>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jQuery must be used from within a dynamic script injected in the page you need before to inject jquery like:

```js
// in my background I normally put code like:

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var rq = request['key'];
    if (rq != undefined && typeof rq == 'string') {
      switch (rq) {
        case 'init':
          ........
          break;
        case 'loadJquery':
          loadJQueryInTab(sender, sendResponse);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

 function loadJQueryInTab(sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, {file: 'third_party/jquery-1.11.2.min.js', allFrames: false}, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, {file: 'js/myScript.js', allFrames: false}, function () {
                ....;
        });
    });
}
```

To create a new tab and get the tabid:

```js
chrome.tabs.create(object createProperties, function callback)

Where callback is:

function( Tab tab) {
  // the current tabid is: tab.id
}
```

Comment: The script that I'm talking about is fired from background script by recall from chrome.tabs.create. Where do I put your code?

Comment: @Lotherad I use this sequence to inject scripts in my scripts in pages....Let me know. Of course, jquery minified is in my addon, I do not use CDN

Comment: @Lotherad in the background page. I use event message to communicate through pages and all the main tasks like yours is executed in the background on a message received.

Comment: @Lotherad I changed my answer, but that's one of the correct way. Let me know more to give you more help.

Comment: Why you don't use chrome.runtime.onMessage? + I don't really understand what is going on in your listener function.

Comment: Ok I will try to execute jQuery file on newly created tab. I need to get id of this tab somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: @Lotherad  I copied the code from my very old sample program I did. You are right, better chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener.

Comment: It's working! Did it like that, in background script:

`chrome.tabs.create({url: myUrl}, function(tab){
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'jquery-2.1.4.min.js'}, function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'scriptToExecute.js'});
   })});`

Comment: Yea I'm just new in the forum so I don't know much about score system. :D Thanks, you helped me a lot!

Comment: I would love to but it is saying 

`Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.`

Comment: And I got a problem now, when I use $('div.class').text() it shows me all those combinated strings but I want to check only first one so when I do $('div.class')[0].text() it says 'text is not a function'. How do I use it then? Sorry if I can't ask that little question in this thread, I just think that it's trifle.

Comment: $('div.class').eq(0).text().  The jQuery eq function is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can include jQuery in your extension and inject it into the page using content script:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [<url regex>],
    "js": ["jquery-2.1.3.min.js"]
}],
```

Comment: I know that but as I wrote earlier, script that I want to use jQuery in is not content script... Do I have to make it content script?

Comment: Nope. You can inject jQuery as content script but your code doesn't have to be a content script.

Comment: `"content_scripts": [
    {
 "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
 "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "myScript.js"]
    }
  ]`